# Does Puzzle Quest on PlayStation 4 include the "Revenge of the Plague Lord" expansion?

Tags: ps4, puzzle-quest

I really loved playing Puzzle Quest back when it was released, and noticed that the [PlayStation 4 version](https://store.playstation.com/#!/en-au/games/puzzle-quest-challenge-of-the-warlords/cid=EP1400-CUSA03933_00-SLUS216920000001) was on sale this week so was considering re-buying it.

There was an expansion made for the game called "Revenge of the Plague Lord" that was released as DLC for some platforms, and bundled with the main game on others.

I couldn't see any reference to the expansion in the description on the store, and it isn't listed as DLC either.  So is it being sold as part of the base game, or is it simply not available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having played through the entirety of Puzzle Quest on the DS (sans expansion) as well as the PS4 version, I did not see any differences. Having looked up what the expansion includes, I can say for certain that the Revenge of the Plague Lord expansion is ***not*** included in the item you linked to (the same version I have on my PS4). The additional character classes were definitely not available.

That said, I cannot find a link to the expansion in the PSN store, nor can I find any articles mentioning it being ported to the PS4, so I do not think it is available.